# is it possible to have a protected ivar declared in a class extension and have a superclass be able to access it or what to do instead?

Tags: objective-c

I have a class which internally uses an ivar. I don't want to expose the ivar in the public interface of the class (the header) but I declare and use it in the implementation file, like so:

```
//--------SomeClass.h--------------
@interface SomeClass : NSObject
@end

//--------SomeClass.m--------------
@implementation SomeClass ()
{
@protected
    NSMutableDictionary *_privateData;
}

@implementation SomeClass
// ...
@end
```

Then in a subclass of SomeClass, I try to access _privateData:

```
//--------SomeSubClass.m--------------
@implementation SomeSubClass

// ...

- (void)someMethod {
    NSLog(@"%@", _privateData); // NOPE
    NSLog(@"%@", self->_privateData); // NOPE
    NSLog(@"%@", super->_privateData); // NOPE
}

// ...

@end
```

But I can't. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to achieve the desired behavior, you should create a subclass header file which declares all of your protected data and `#import` it in your subclass' `.m` file.

MammalSubclass.h:

```
@interface Mammal () {
   @protected
   NSMutableDictionary *_privateData;
}

//...

@end
```

Human.m:

```
#import "Human.h"
#import "MammalSubclass.h"

@implementation Human //subclasses Mammal

- (void)someMethod {
   NSLog(@"%@", _privateData);
}

//...

@end
```

Comment: yeah I figured; another option too would be, for that matter, creating a private or "friendship" (terminology ala C++) protocol. Just thought maybe there was a way around it.

Comment: looking at class dumps of modern Apple frameworks e.g. CloudKit, it seems they are choosing to make their protected ivars properties instead. This makes me wonder if they are accessing self.privateData in subclass inits and dealloc which is usually bad practice.